# What is a valid use for Response.Redirect("SomeURL", false)?

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET I frequently use Response.Redirect to redirect the end user to another page on my system. I always set the second parameter to true to immediately end the response.

For the life of me, I can't think of a reason why anybody would ever set that parameter to false. What's the point of continuing generating a page when the end user's browser is just going to be redirected to a different page immediately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Response.Redirect` does not mean that The **Page-lifecycle** has ended on the server, it just **sends a header** to the client.

Perhaps you want to redirect the user first and THEN save his large amount of uploaded data to the database?

`HttpServerUtility.Transfer` by the way does terminate the Page-lifecycle, but it does not send a header, it simply serves a different page.

Comment: Note: when you use Transfer the URL will remain the same

Comment: I'll accept your answer as correct. However I read your reponse as "Theoretically, you could use it this way" rather than "In the past, I used it this way". What I'd like to know is do you ever use the response.redirect method with the second parameter false?

Comment: Actually, I always set it to false. I prefer to use Response.Redirect("http://www.yahoo.com", false); instead of Response.Redirect("http://www.yahoo.com");

Answer (score 6):

```
Response.Redirect(..., true);
```

client will be sent the redirect for the new page, processing will stop as a thread abort will occur

```
Response.Redirect(..., false);
```

client will be sent the redirect for the new page, current page will be allowed to continue processing, perhaps some cleanup work to do or something else

client will never see the results from current page in either cases

Answer (score 1):

Why not. May be you have some things to complete on this page before the processes of a page will be killed. Writing to file and then colsing it for example. Or making some changes in DB, with proper ending of connection.

Answer (score -1):

`Response.Rediect("any page like Default.aspx");`

When the control reach on this statement our page will be jump to the page that is specified into the brackets. The page may be .aspx, .asp.htm  etc...

Comment: No point repeating things that are already explained in other answers.